# Django grant permissions on/ after saving object

Tags: django, django-guardian

I have a Django model which includes specific permissions. I want to be able to assign permissions to those users in the `assigned_to field`. I am using `django-guardian` to manage the permissions.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from guardian.shortcuts import assign_perm


class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, default=None, blank=True, null=True
    )
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related"
    )


    permissions = (
        ('view_project', 'View project'),
    )
```

I have tried to implement a custom save method. If I try and do it before the save:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for user in self.assigned_to:
             assign_perm('view_project', user, self)
             super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I get an error:

```
    ObjectNotPersisted: Object <project_name> needs to be persisted first
```

If I do it after the save (which I guess is wrong anyhow):

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        for user in self.assigned_to:
             assign_perm('view_project', user, self)
```

I get an `Type Error 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`.

Should I be using a `post-save` signal for this? What is the best approach for what I assume is a common pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused because the field itself is not iterable, you need to specify the queryset using `filter` or `all`:

```
for user in self.assigned_to.all():
    assign_perm('view_project', user, self)
```

However, as you commented, this needs to be done after the parent model instance is saved, so yes you can either create a `post_save` signal to accomplish this or save the M2M relations in your view after your call to `save` the parent instance.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work. The super method is called but `self.assigned_to.all()` is empty. It only works if I later explicitly add user: `assigned_to.add([users])`. isn't this because Django actually adds `ManyToMany` related fields after saving?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was responding to your not iterable error and overlooked this. I'll update the answer.